Flutter WEB ColorType.mostLight
I currently have an application in flutter that regardless of whether I am in dev or pro it always shows this message in the console. ColorType.mostLight I would like to know if there is a way for it not to be rendered no matter how many thousands of times in the console. that I will not end up forgetting about flutter and resorting to other technologies. I have a hybrid app and at the moment I have this problem in the PWA or WEB version. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

i solved the problem is on flutter_neumorphic packaged... i edit this and comment debug print console... actions

ready i have solve the problem... this alert or debugPrint is for one package flutter_nuemorphic... the problem is solved
